# Obtaining Authorization Code from Spring OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am trying to obtain an authorization code from a Spring OAuth 2.0 authorization server using simple CURL command.

```
curl -v --header "Authorization: Basic hasfhfashfakhsfakhf712641246" "http://0.0.0.0:0000/oauth-server/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=dummyclient&client_secret=dummyclient&redirect_uri=http://oauth2server/oauth2callback/"
```

However, instead of getting back a redirect URL with the code, I am getting back a 302 redirect response to the login URL. Since I am already sending the username, password in the Authorization Header, is there a way to skip the login page redirect and get the Authorization Code directly?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to tell curl to follow redirect with the `-L` flag

```
curl -L -v --header "Authorization: Basic hasfhfashfakhsfakhf712641246" "http://0.0.0.0:0000/oauth-server/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=dummyclient&client_secret=dummyclient&redirect_uri=http://oauth2server/oauth2callback/"
```

Comment: Thanks, but following the redirect now gives me a login page. However, the point is that I am already passing the authorization information in the header, so, I don't really expect a login page here.